# Lowess smoothing in R that extract values given X

Tags: r, smoothing

In R when I use lowess() and plot the smooth using line() function, am I able to extract the smoothed y value given any value of the x? How to do it, please? Thanks!

any alternative smoothing methods in R that I can extract a smoothed y-value given a specified x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch from `lowess` to the newer `loess` that replaces it, then you get a predict method.  From `example(predict.loess)`:

```
cars.lo <- loess(dist ~ speed, cars)
predict(cars.lo, data.frame(speed = seq(5, 30, 1)), se = TRUE)   
# extrapolation
cars.lo2 <- loess(dist ~ speed, cars, control = loess.control(surface = "direct"))
predict(cars.lo2, data.frame(speed = seq(5, 30, 1)), se = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks, so i just specify a specific speed value and will get a predicted value right? thanks

Comment: Generally speaking if you model `y ~ X` where the `X` are in a `data.frame`, you want a similar `data.frame` (with all columns present, apart from `y`) for `predict` methods.    Here it is simpler as `loess()` usually just takes one variable.  But note that the example _still_ creates a `data.frame` as that is in fact required for `predict()`.  Seems weird at first, makes sense later as you use it more often across different modeling functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. but sometimes when i specify one arbitrary value of X, and want to use this to find predicted smoothed y (through loess), it prints a dataframe that contains a lot of numbers. i don't really know how to interpret.

Comment: sometimes the smoothed loess is zigzag, not smooth even with different degree of span specified.

Comment: Well it extrapolates from _local_ smoothing so there can probably be values for the parameter, and some data, where this is non-sensical ...